How to typset sideheadings?
I want to typset sideheads, just as they are often used in legal documents, and then be able to refer back to these sideheads with the standard machinery of \ref, \nameref, \cref and the rest.
A sidehead, as I understand it, is short phrase printed in the margin, often with special formatting (e.g. bold, small caps, etc.) which acts like a heading in that it marks a certain part of the document as doing a certain thing. Unlike other headings though, sideheads do not break the flow of the paragraph text -- they sit to the side. Knuth uses sideheads in The TeXbook (though they are always printed in a set at the top of the page).
I would like to be able to insert code for sideheads anywhere in the text, with a single commmand (e.g. \sidehead{<the title of my sidehead>}) and have a margin note with appropriate typography (small caps) show up in the margin next to the surrounding text (so unlike Knuth's setup). I don't want the paragraph to break around the sideheading in any way (in this respect I want them to behave like margin notes). I want the text of the sidehead command to be typeset, but no counter or numbering.
In all other respects though, I would like my sideheads to behave like sections. I want to be able to include them, in order, in a table of contents, and associate them with page numbers, and I also want to be able to add labels to them and then refer to them with cleverref, nameref and pageref (this is their primary utility -- I want to be able to direct readers to very specific parts of my work, from other parts of that same work).
I have tried defining my own section, as described here, but the titling package forces the paragraph text to break around the section (I think -- MWE below, but I can't find a way to prevent this).
\documentclass{article}

\title{A title}

% Sideheads
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcounter{sidehead}

\titleclass{\sidehead}{straight}[\subsection]

\titleformat{\sidehead}[display]
  {}% format (empty)
  {}% label (empty)
  {0em}% space (effectively empty)
  {\marginpar{#1}}% before code (after code ignored)

\titlespacing*{\sidehead}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \sidehead{Test} \emph{The
  sidehead should not cause the text to break}, but it does. It has
survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

\marginpar{Margin note}This (see right) is how I \emph{want} it to
look, but \verb|marginpage| notes don't show up in the TOC or have
\verb|nameref|-able labels.

\end{document}

